# Lotus Notes - replicating only certain calendar types

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I’ve been asked if it’s possible to make a replica of a mail database that only contains contacts and calendar data. Furthermore the replicated calendar data should only be of the following types

All Day Event

Meeting

Appointment

(meaning NO ToDo, Reminders, Anniversary and Event Announcement).

and ONLY if they are not marked as “Mark Available” and “Mark Private”.

Is this somehow achievable with a selection formula from within the “New replica” setting and if so, how should it look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is quite easy. The formula would look like this:

```
SELECT Form = "Appointment" & AppointmentType ="2" : "3" : "0" & 
@IsUnavailable($PublicAccess) & BookFreeTime = "1"
```

AppointmentType 0 = Appointment
AppointmentType 3 = Meeting
AppointmentType 2 = All Day Event

If $PublicAccess is present, then it is not private. 
If BookFreetime = "1" then it is not marked as "Available"..

Answer (score 1):

After looking around the web an reading feedback here, my final formula looks like this

```
SELECT (AppointmentType = "0" | AppointmentType = "2" | AppointmentType = "3") 
& @IsAvailable(CalendarDateTime) & CalendarDateTime <= @Adjust(@Today;0;1;0;0;0;0) & 
CalendarDatetime >= @Today &  (OrgConfidential = "" & BookFreeTime = "") | Form = "Person"
```

I "tweaked" it a bit to only replicate calender entries 1 month ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because you said that it works but i would write like this 
    @IsMember( AppointmentType ; "2" : "3" : "0")
Tell us